# Пройтись по всему объекту Json

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Имеется json файл, который состоит из объекта и вложенных в него массивов

```
{
    "id": 523,
    "title": "Зеленое яблоко",
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 601,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 602,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 603,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 604,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 605,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 606,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 607,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 608,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 609,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 610,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 4"
        },
        {
            "id": 611,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 5"
        },
        {
            "id": 612,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg",
            "name_category": "Категория 6"
        }
    ],
    "hit_to_price": [
        {
            "id": 613,
            "name": "Товар 1",
            "old_price": 250,
            "new_price": 200,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 614,
            "name": "Товар 2",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 615,
            "name": "Товар 3",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 300,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 616,
            "name": "Товар 4",
            "old_price": 200,
            "new_price": 200,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 617,
            "name": "Товар 5",
            "old_price": 450,
            "new_price": 200,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "promotions": [
        {
            "id": 618,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 619,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 620,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 621,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 622,
            "image": "https://i0.wp.com/readok.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fruits-veggies.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "cooking": [
        {
            "id": 623,
            "name": "Блюдо 1",
            "old_price": 250,
            "new_price": 200,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 624,
            "name": "Блюдо 2",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 625,
            "name": "Блюдо 3",
            "old_price": 350,
            "new_price": 300,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 626,
            "name": "Блюдо 2",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 627,
            "name": "Блюдо 2",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "sub_categories": [
        {
            "id": 628,
            "name_category": "Овощи и фрукты",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg",
            "count": 25
        },
        {
            "id": 629,
            "name_category": "Бакалея",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "count": 28
        },
        {
            "id": 630,
            "name_category": "Хлеб и выпечка",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg",
            "count": 25
        },
        {
            "id": 631,
            "name_category": "Правильное питание",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "count": 40
        },
        {
            "id": 632,
            "name_category": "Удар по ценам",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg",
            "count": 42
        },
        {
            "id": 633,
            "name_category": "Хлеб и выпечка",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "count": 34
        },
        {
            "id": 634,
            "name_category": "Правильное питание",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg",
            "count": 27
        },
        {
            "id": 635,
            "name_category": "Бакалея",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "count": 29
        },
        {
            "id": 636,
            "name_category": "Овощи и фрукты",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572684241_31.jpg",
            "count": 35
        },
        {
            "id": 637,
            "name_category": "Хлеб и выпечка",
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "count": 32
        }
    ],
    "supermarket_products": [
        {
            "id": 638,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис первый сорт",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250
        },
        {
            "id": 639,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис второй сорт",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 300
        },
        {
            "id": 640,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис третий сорт",
            "old_price": 300,
            "new_price": 250
        },
        {
            "id": 641,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис четвертый сорт",
            "old_price": 400,
            "new_price": 300
        },
        {
            "id": 642,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис пятый сорт",
            "old_price": 400,
            "new_price": 350
        },
        {
            "id": 643,
            "image": "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-11/1572781257_3.jpg",
            "name": "Рис шестой сорт",
            "old_price": 550,
            "new_price": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

Мне нужно пройтись по всему объекту и сравнить id в массивах с сохраненными у меня в базе id и извлечь его, если оба id совпадают

Comment: И что удалось предпринять? Почему не получилось?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Пока ничего не предпринял, нет идей как это реализовать

Comment: @mrEvgenX я могу пройтись по одному массиву и достать из него объект с id, но не понимаю как пройтись по всем массивам сразу

Comment: Не понятно что извлечь и какие id должны совпадать. Есть id events, есть id categories итд, есть id самого обьекта. Какие id именно вам нужны. По идее тут ничего сложного, важно знать что именно необходимо. Опишите подробнее

Comment: @AVRamones я сначала получаю эти списки в разных местах и добавляю некоторые в корзину (база данных) и уже при переходе на экран корзины мне нужно сверить id, которые в базе, со всеми id из json файла и вывести совпадающиеся в список.

Comment: Для начала определитесь чем парсить будете, если вообще будете. Как по мне, проще обычным поиском по строке пройтись, найти `"id":` и считать число после и до запятой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете [спарсить](https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo) его в объект:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "your_json";
YourJsonObject yourJsonObject= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, YourJsonObject.class);
```

А дальше уже спокойно сделать желаемое.

Comment: А чем плох просто `JsonObject` для таких целей?

Comment: Может быть и не чем. Я просто предложил один из вариантов, который пришел в голову. Если у вас есть предложения лучше - напишите в качестве ответа.